# How to share screen in app via Bluetooth from one iPhone to another iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

Hi i am developing an app so i have an requirement i.e in my app i want to share the screen via bluetooth to connected devices . i searched a lot but not getting any solution is it possible in iOS? if any one can tell it should appreciate thanks.

Comment: why it is in negative mode plz let me know it will help to next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use MultipeerConnectivityFramework or Core Bluetooth Framework, But keep in mind Apple not allowing to connect devices which are not MFi licensed.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all ensure that device is MFi Licensed Accessories.
2. Please check device is MFi Licensed Accessories or not via using below link